# Issue rendering large javascript in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

In my application, we generate a url that executes large javascript on android webview. But when we load that url on default native webview, javascript is not properly renendered even after enabling javascript to true. That javascripts executes perfecly on launching it on google chrome as external browser.. But we need to load that url in webview only, is there any way to use google chrome in native webview in android..

Comment: webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient())

Comment: I tried this.. its not working.. My javascript is properly working on 4.4 kitkat but on earlier versions, it now executing...